# Understanding Equation to Straight Line in Oblique Coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

I believe I've spent way to much time trying to grasp a certain part of this proof. This is provided in S.L. Loney's book on The Elements of Coordinate Geometry.

*Let LPL' be a straight line which cuts the axis of Y at a distance c from the origin and is inclined at an angle θ to the axis of X.*

*Let P be any point on the straight line. Draw PNM parallel to the axis of y to meet OX in M,
and let it meet the straight line through C parallel to the axis of x in the point N.*

*Let P be the point (x,y), so that
CN = 0M = x, and NP = MP – OC = y – c.*

*Since CPN = PNN' – PCN' = ω – θ, we have $y – c \over x$$ = $$NP \over CN $$ = $$sinNCP \over sinCPN$$ = $$sinθ \over sin(ω – θ)$.*

I'll stop here, for this is the part I can't at all grasp. Why exactly is $NP \over CN $$ = $$sinNCP \over sinCPN$. For we are currently talking of oblique coordinates, and there is no right angle to orient ourselves with. Perhaps this question is laughable; but I would still appreciate the reader if I were properly answered by them. Below is provided a picture for visual aid: [image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, your question isn't laughable ! $\frac{\sin(NCP)}{ \sin(CPN)}=\frac{NP}{CN}$ is just the sine law in a triangle, which doesn't necessitate axes, but assumes an ambient Euclidean space (said otherwise the "true" lengths can be measured on the figure"). Have you seen what happens in the final formula when $\omega = \frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: Thank you very much, this was most helpful! I'm very familiar with the law of sines; yet, somehow it must have slipped my mind during reasoning. I've observed that the value $sin\theta\over sin(\omega – \theta)$ collapses into $tan\theta$; as in the slope-intercept form for conventional rectangular axes $y = mx + c$. I admire the way mathematics aligns in these predicatable ways. Thank you, again, for your time.